# How to flatten a single nested hash key?

Tags: perl

I have a data structure flattened by [`Hash::Flatten`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Flatten)

For example,

```
flatten( { a => [ 'x', { b => 'y' } ] } )
```

produces

```
my $flat = {
   'a:0'   => 'x'
   'a:1.b' => 'y',
};
```

I want to generate a flattened hash key from the a list of keys and indexes from a key [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver)'s functions would accept.

For example,

```
my @key = ('a', 1, 'b');
```

should return

```
my $key = "a:1.b";
```

I have looked at Hash::Flatten, but it seems it can only flatten the whole hash, which is not what I am looking for. I just want to flatten a single (nested) key at a time.

To avoid replicating the escaping mechanism of Hash::Flatten, I tried the following:

```
use Data::Diver   qw( DiveVal );
use Hash::Flatten qw( flatten );

my @key = ('a', 1, 'b');

DiveVal(my $h = {}, @key) = 1;
my ($key) = keys(%{ flatten($h) );
```

But that can just as easily return `a:0` as `a:1.b`. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Ok, the data structure with two elements `$flat_hash` is not related to the large data structure. The  `$flat_hash` has two elements here since Data::Diver creates two elements due to the array index is 1 and not 0. Ideally, I would like to avoid the trick of calling Data::Diver just to create a temporary hash `$flat_hash`, so I can use Hash::Flatten on that. It seems overkill for a simple job.. It would be better to go directly from `@nested_key` to the flattened key..

Comment: It involves som escaping of the separator characters. So I was looking for a possible CPAN solution before starting coding from scratch..

Comment: Hash::Flatten does not have a key generator. You could submit your function to the author for inclusion. It would be a useful addition.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, thanks for the advice. It seems that the source code for Hash::Flatten already has two functions `_escape` and `_unescape`.. so the (only?) problem is that they are not part of the exported/public interface of that package..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to do without reference to either `Hash::Flatten` or `Data::Diver`. The latter's `DiveVal` distinguishes between hash keys and array indices using the regex `/^-?\d+$/`, so we can do the same to discover whether a item in a sequence's `Hash::Flatten` default contraction should be preceded by a colon `:` (array index) or a dot `.` (hash key).

That gives the subroutine `flatten_key` below

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @key = ('a', 1, 'b');
my $key = flatten_key(@key);
say $key;

say flatten_key(qw/ a b c 1 2 3 /);

sub flatten_key {
  join '', shift, map /^-?\d+$/ ? ":$_" : ".$_", @_;
}
```

**output**

```
a:1.b
a.b.c:1:2:3
```

---

**Update**

If you need to use the `Data::Diver` convention that any value passed as a scalar reference is a hash *key*, even if it looks like a number, then you can expand that subroutine like this. It's slightly more awkward because the first item in the sequence needs to be processed as well, but for some reason it doesn't take a delimiter character. So I've chosen to add a delimiter to all the items and then remove it from the first.

```
say flatten_key('a', 'b', \1, \2, 'c', 'd', 1, 2);

sub flatten_key {
  my @key = map {
    ref()     ? ".$$_" :
    /^-?\d+$/ ? ":$_" :
                ".$_"
  } @_;
  $key[0] =~ s/^[:.]//;
  join '', @key;
}
```

**output**

```
a.b.1.2.c.d:1:2
```

---

**Update**

Also accounting for hash keys that themselves contain dots or colons:

```
say flatten_key(qw/ a .. :: b /);

sub flatten_key {
  my @key = map {
    (my $s = ref() ? $$_ : $_) =~ s/(?=[:.\\])/\\/g;
    /^-?\d+$/ ? ":$s" : ".$s"
  } @_;
  $key[0] =~ s/^[:.]//;
  join '', @key;
}
```

**output**

```
a.\.\..\:\:.b
```

Comment: In general we also need to consider the case where the keys themselves contains the separator characters `.` or `:`. So they need to be escaped properly.

Comment: @HåkonHægland:  Okay I didn't spot that. I've added my final version!

Comment: @HåkonHægland: In case there is a real backslash in the key itself, which would otherwise be considered to be escaping the following character

Comment: But we know that there are only two valid escape sequences to consider? Namely `\.` and `\:` if a key already contains for example `\:`, we will first replace `:` with `\:` to obtain `\\:` so it should be possible to reconstruct the key without having to escape the escape also?

Comment: `@key = ("a\\", "b")` and `@key = ("a\\.b")` would produce the same flat key (`a\\.b`).

Comment: @ikegami Would not `"a\\.b"` produce `"a\\\.b"` whereas `"a\\"` and `"b"` would give `"a\\.b"` ?

Comment: huh... `"a\\\.b"` and `"a\\.b"` produce the same string.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I think I can see the problem. For example, reconstruction of flattened key `"a\.b"` would give `@key = ("a.b")`. But the original could also have been `@key = ("a\", "b")` ..

Comment: I added some more functionality to this and uploaded the code for review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87066/perl-subroutines-to-flatten-and-unflatten-a-complex-hash-or-array-key

Answer (score 2):

Only the key in which you are interested will have a defined value, so only a small change is needed.

```
use Data::Diver   qw( DiveVal );
use Hash::Flatten qw( flatten );

sub flat_key {
   DiveVal(my $h = {}, @_) = 1;
   my $flat = flatten($h);
   return ( grep $flat->{$_}, keys(%$flat) )[0];
}

my @key = ('a', 1, 'b');
my $key = flat_key(@key);  # a:1.b
```

Because this uses Data::Diver, you can also use references to indicate that a number is really a hash key.

```
my @key = ('a', 1, 'b');
my $key = flat_key(map \$_, @key);  # a.1.b
```

Alternatively, the escaping mechanism is well documented.

```
sub _flat_key_escape {
   my ($s) = @_;
   $s =~ s/([\\.:])/\\$1/g;
   return $s;
}

sub flat_key {
   my $key;
   die("usage") if !@_;
   for my $subkey (@_) {
      if (ref($subkey))                { $key .= '.' . _flat_key_escape($$subkey); }
      elsif ($subkey !~ /^-?[0-9]+\z/) { $key .= '.' . _flat_key_escape($subkey);  }
      else                             { $key .= ':' . _flat_key_escape($subkey);  }
   }

   return substr($key, 1);
}
```